# Centripetal acceleration for a polyline

Tags: trigonometry

Given a polyline (x and y coordinates) in Cartesian coordinate system and time component, how can I estimate centripetal acceleration (let's say an average one)? (I have a list of  pairs. Each pair  was measured at 1 minute interval. So, from this information, I can easily estimate speed and acceleration.)

I know that the centripetal acceleration it is the rate of change of tangential velocity. But the problem is that tangential velocity formula involves the radius of circular path, and my path (polyline) just has some curvatures. So, I don't know how to get the radius.

As a starting point, I think that it's necessary to estimate angles using these formulas:

```
radian = math.atan2((y2 - y1),(x2 - x1))
degrees = radian * 180 / math.pi
```

But I don't know how to proceed from it. Do I need to estimate all angles between sequential  points and then integrate these angles over time...?

Any clarification is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is your polyline spare or dense ? I mean is it more like a polygon or like a smooth curve ? In the first case, you have a problem as the centripetal acceleration is null, except at corners where it is infinite. In the second case, you will need to perform numerical integration combined with smoothing, for instance with Savitzky–Golay filters.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Please see an example of a polyline in my updated post (it's a rough example, but it's good enough to give an idea)

Comment: I wouldn't call that a polyline, but that's unimportant. You are in the second case, you should use smoothed derivatives. The Cartesian acceleration vector is just the second derivative of the coordinates over time. The centripetal component is obtained by projecting on the normal to the trajectory, itself perpendicular to the speed vector (first derivatives).

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Thank you. Could you please give some link where I can see an example of how to project on the normal to the trajectory?

Comment: Cross posted on Physics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160883/centripetal-acceleration-for-a-polyline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numerical safety, I recommend to use the [Savitzky-Golay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) filters for derivation.

Use them to compute the first and second derivatives of the coordinates over time.

The speed vector is $\vec v=(\dot x(t),\dot y(t))$. The acceleration vector is $\vec a=(\ddot x(t),\ddot y(t))$.

The centripetal acceleration is the component of the acceleration orthogonal to the trajectory, i.e. orthogonal to the speed vector. It is given by

$$a_c=||\vec a\times\frac{\vec v}v||.$$

Similarly, the tangential acceleration is given by the projection on the tangent,

$$a_t=\vec a\cdot\frac{\vec v}v.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, do you know any R (or Python) package that can decrease hard coding time to solve this task?

Comment: Numpy/Scipy or... Google. Coding this is peanuts once you have chosen the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you must have a $\textbf{r}(t)$ function. Your polyline can be probably considered as one. If you want constant speed, maybe you will have problems.

The curvature of a such curve can be expressed by the formula $\kappa=\frac{|\dot{\textbf{r}}\times \ddot{\textbf{r}}|}{|\dot{\textbf{r}}^3|}$. Its recipe is radius, which can be substituted into the formula of the centrifugal acceleration of the circular movement ($\textbf{a}=\frac{v^2}{R}$).

Comment: The speed is not constant, it's changing over time (please see my post update). Do I understand correctly that I must use the formula of the centrifugal acceleration of the circular movement ($\textbf{a}=\frac{\textbf{v}^2}{\textbf{r}}$), in which I must substitute r by k (curvature)? If so, could you please indicate how to estimate the curvature of a polyline?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Oops! In the second formula there is $R$, which is the radius of the circular curvature. It is the recipe of $\kappa$. It is a different thing as your $\textbf{r}(t)$ function! And, you know $\textbf{v}$, because it is the derivative or $\textbf{r}$.

Comment: Could you please add steps that I must follow to get the answer? I understood that it's necessary to start with the second formula by substituting R with k...However, I still don't have a complete understanding of your procedure.